# How to use coordination of another viewport in Grid package?

Tags: r

I want analyse the climate data in several cities and for each city a chart is produced using ggplot2. And as underlayer I made a map and want to locate the chart for each city in the map with the right position. I think it is not possible to plot them directly with ggplot2, unless  I define a new geom. A better way may be using the Grid package and place the viewports in the right way somehow, that means the viewport center should be set to the precise place with longitude and latitude. Is it possible to use the coordination of another viewport(here the map plot)?

Comment: you should provide a reproducible example. how do you create your map? what do you mean by chart here? Is it a picture?

Comment: the book "R Graphics" led me to the R graph gallery website. I found the solution there.

http://rgraphgallery.blogspot.de/2013/04/rg-histogram-bar-chart-over-map.html
http://rgraphgallery.blogspot.de/2013/04/rg-plot-bar-or-pie-chart-over-world-map.html